# Seeing posts on the main question view where the user name is a recent answer provider and not the original poster

Tags: discussion, user-interface, users

I've been thinking that I am going nuts, but quite often I see questions on the main question view where the "asker" name is in fact the name of somebody who has *answered* the question. When it happens, and I click into the question, when I go back and look at the main view again the question invariably shows the actual "asker" name instead of the person who last provided an answer.

I don't have a lot of specifics about this because it does not happen all the time. Almost always, what's shown in the main queue of questions is the accurate user identity of the asker of the question.

Clearly this is not a major issue, but it made me really confused for some time. The identity and reputation of the question asker is kind-of important to a person perusing the question queue; otherwise the identity information wouldn't be shown, I would think. There have been times when I've seen a very basic beginner question in the queue attributed to a user I know to be very experienced, and that's quite confusing; however when I click into the question what I see is a very low-rep user question.

Comment: I believe you're seeing the same thing as the other two folks who previously reported this. What's odd is that it's intermittent. I personally haven't been able to reproduce it. I suppose more information is always helpful to the developers.

Comment: @CodyGray I am able to reproduce this all the time. We need to keep the notification growing (don't click it for a while) and then you click on it. All the new questions where there is an edit or a new answer will show this behavior (the last activity will be picked).

Comment: @Temani Can you update the original question with those details, please? I’ll tag it as [[meta-tag:status-review]] to bring it to the attention of the team.

Comment: @CodyGray it's done